# 1024 bit pseudo random generator in verilog for FPGA

Tags: random, verilog, fpga, mersenne-twister

I want to generate random vectors of length 1024  in verilog . I have looked at  certain implementations like Tausworth generators and Mersenne Twisters. 
Most Mersenne twisters have 32 bit/ 64 bit outputs . I want to simulate an error pattern of 1024 bits with some probability p . So , I generate a 32 bit random number (uniformly distributed) using Mersenne Twister. Since I have 32 bit random numbers , this number will be in the range 0 to 2^32-1 . After this I set the number to 1, if the number generated from this 32 bit value is less than p*(2^32-1) .Otherwise the number is mapped to a 0 in my 1023 bit vector . Basically , each 32 bit number is used to generate a bit in the 1023 vector according to the probabilistic distribution .

The above method implies that I need 1024 clock cycles to generate each 1024 bit vector. Is there any other way which allows me to do this quickly ? I understand that I could use several instance of the Mersenne Twister in parallel using different seed values but I was afraid that those numbers will not be truly random and that there will be collisions . Is there something that I am doing wrong or something that I am missing ? I would really appreciate your help

Comment: I don't think that will work. The probability of a bit being '1' is p. So if p is low you get 1024 bit numbers with few 1-es. e.g with p very low you have high probability of having only 1 bit set which gives the numbers 1,2,4,8...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, 
So I read a bit about Mersenne Twisters in general from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). I accept I did't outright get all of it but I got this: Given a seed value (to initialise the array), the module generates 32 bit random numbers.

Now, from your description above, it takes one cycle to compute one random number.

So your problem basically boils to to it's mathematics rather than being about `verilog` as such.

I would try to explain the math of it as best as I can.

You have a 32 bit uniformly distributed random number. So, the probability of any one bit being `high` or `low` is exactly (well, close to, cause psuedo random) `0.5`.

Let's forget that this is a pseudo random generator, because that is the best you are going to get(So let's consider this as our ideal).

***Even if we generate 5 numbers one after the other, the probability of each one being any particular number is still uniformly distributed. So if we concatenate these five numbers, we will get a 160 bit completely random number.***

---

If it's still not clear,  consider this way.

I'm gonna break the problem down. Let's say we have a 4-bit random number generator (RNG), and we require 16 bit random numbers.

Each output of the RNG would be a hex digit with a uniform probability distribution. So the probability of getting some particular digit (say... A) is `1/16`. Now I want to make a 4 digit Hex number (say... 0xA019).

Probability of getting A as the Most Significant digit = `1/16`

Probability of getting 0 as digit number 2 = `1/16`

Probability of getting 1 as digit number 3 = `1/16`

Probability of getting 9 as the Least Significant digit = `1/16`

***So the probability of getting 0xA019 = `1/(2^16)`.*** Infact, probability of getting any four digit hex number would be exactly the same. Now, extend the same logic to Base-32 Number systems with 32 digit numbers as the required output and you have your solution.

---

So, we see, we could do with just 32 repetitions of the Mersenne twister to get the 1024 bit output (that would take 32 cycles, still kinda slow). What you could also do is synthesise 32 twisters in parallel (that would give you the output in one stroke but would be very heavy on the fpga in terms of area, power constraints).

The best way to go about this would be to try for some middle ground (maybe 4 parallel twisters running in 8 cycles). This would really be a question of the end application of the module and the power and timing constraints that you need for that application.

As for giving different seed values, most PRNGs usually have provision for input seeds just to increase randomness, from what I read on Mersenne Twisters, it has the same case.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I thought about your comment . The problem here is the following : We need the 1024 bit number to have few ones . Basically , the idea is to make a 3 error correction decoder . What that means is that I have a 1024 bit pattern . You can flip upto 3 bits (position does not matter) and my decoder will be able to correct those errors. To analyse the performance of my decoder , I need to be able to run simulations . I need vectors (random) for that purpose . Now , if I concatenate 32 numbers each 32 bits to get this 1024 bit pattern , each one of the 32 bit numbers will be between 0 and 2^32-1

Comment: So, it is highly likely that I am going to get more than 3 errors in the entire 1024 bit codeword . As I told earlier, my decoder is only capable of correcting upto 3 random errors. If it gets more than that , it will just declare a decoding failure and that will happen a lot if we follow the scheme that you suggested.

Comment: It seems as though you want to simulate an error correcting decoder,

Comment: So basically you want the random number generator to give you a number with, at most, three ones. Then I suppose you would be flipping the bits (in the original 1024 bit input) at those positions where the random number has ones.

Comment: If that is the case, A possible alternate way to go about this would be to simply generate 3 11-bit numbers, These would give you three numbers in 0-1023. You could then take a decision to flip or not flip the respective bit based on the most significant digit of the number.